# AI Health Decrement

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am currently developing a game in unity, I need an enemy to attack something and for that objects health to decrease.  Basically the attack sequence is: -

1) Play attack animation
2) Decrease health 
3) Repeat until dead

Edited:
Sorry should have shown my code, here it is:

```
// Check if AI is in attack range
if (transform.position == TargetPostion) {

    // If the target has more than 0 health
    if (TargetHealthScript.health > 0) {

        // Play the animation and then decrement health
        animation.Play("bite");
        TargetHealthScript.decrementHealth(10.0f);
    }
}
```

The script to do this is written in C#

Currently I have this working to an extent however, the health decrement function keeps getting called repeatedly, I need a way to slow it down.  I have tried to use Coroutines with a yield statement without success.

If anyone has any suggestions I would be grateful

Thanks

Comment: Showing your code is expected if you want people to find the issue.

Comment: When have you set up the 'decrease health' to occur? Do you have a callback (or a timer) to tell you when the 'play attack animation' has completed, and then call 'decrease health' only once?

Comment: coolmine - Sorry have now edited to include my code, OnlineCop - My decrease health occurs in the update function, and yes decrease health should only be called once

Comment: One of the problems I see is that your `transform.position` is not going to change between your current test and the next time the `Update()` check occurs. Do you have some kind of "bounce back" effect when the collision occurs? Otherwise, set a flag to let your code know that you're in a "blinking, don't recalculate a hit" state (like old games do when your player gets hit and starts flashing).

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [Update](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.Update.html) function if you know how long the animation will take and use Time.deltaTime[enter link description here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/Time-deltaTime.html) to figure out how much time has passed.

Then decrease the health based on them.

Comment: not saying that i recommend that, but you can set triggers in animations if you are using mechanim